# How do you prove $a$ is in $\cap_{n=1}^\infty (a - {1 \over n} , b)$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to understand why $[a,b)= \cap_{n=1}^\infty (a - {1 \over n} , b)$. My problem is that it would naively seem $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a - {1 \over n} , b) = (a,b)$, but as $a \notin (a,b)$ then how can $a$ be in $\cap_{n=1}^\infty (a - {1 \over n} , b)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a-\frac1n,b)$?

Comment: Hint: what does it mean to say that a point belongs to an intersection of some collection of sets?

Comment: Doesn't $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a - {1 \over n} , b)= (a - 0 , b) = (a,b)$?

Answer (score 3):

If $a<b$, $a$ belongs to $(a-1/n,b)$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Hence it belongs to the intersection $\cap_{n=1}^\infty (a - {1 \over n} , b)$.

Comment: What I'm saying is that $a$ does not belong to $(a - 1 / \infty , b) = (a - 0,b) = (a,b)$ and if $(a - 1 / \infty , b)$ is an open set in the intersection then how can $a$ belong to the intersection?

Comment: Wait... wait... wait... Alarm... alarm... alarm... $(a-1/n, b)$ is a subset of the reals. You probably know what the limit of a sequence is. But how do you define the limit of a set? It would be interesting that you ask yourself this question.

Comment: An arbitrary intersection of open sets doesn't have to be open.  And in this context there's really no such thing as $a - \frac{1}{\infty}$.  You can easily see that $a$ is in each *component* of the intersection, and by definition that means it's in the infinite intersection.

Comment: $(a-1/\infty,b)$ is totally irrelevant; it simply doesn't come up. (In fact $\lim_n(a-1/n,b)=[a,b)$, not what you said. But again that's simply irrelevant to the question.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich And I doubt that the OP is accounted to [set theoritic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit).

Answer (score 0):

$a\in(a-1/n,b),\forall n$ (because $a-1/n\lt a\lt b$) $\implies a\in\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty(a-1/n,b)$.

In fact, $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty(a-1/n,b)=[a,b)$.

Comment: But is $a$ in $(a - 1 / \infty , b)$?

Comment: $n$ approaches infinity, but is always a natural number.  $\infty$ isn't a number.

Answer (score 0):

We have to show that $a\in \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(a-\frac{1}{n},b)$. For this we need to show that $a \in (a-\frac{1}{n},b),~ \forall~ n \in \mathbb{N}$. For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ clearly $\frac{1}{n}>0$. Therefore $a>a-\frac{1}{n}$. Now from the definition of open interval $(a-\frac{1}{n},b)=\lbrace x :~ a-\frac{1}{n}<x<b \rbrace$, it is clear that $a\in (a-\frac{1}{n},b), ~ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Which proves the result.